# Using cv2 in google meet/zoom call

Tags: python, opencv

I would like to know how I could implement the code I have written in python OpenCV into a google meet/Zoom call. I am relatively new to OpenCV.

```
from cv2 import cv2
import numpy as np

import pyvirtualcam


def empty(a):
    pass

    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    cap.set(3, 640)
    cap.set(4, 480)
    cap.set(10, 100)

    cv2.namedWindow("TrackBars")
    cv2.resizeWindow("TrackBars", 640, 240)
    cv2.createTrackbar("Hue Min", "TrackBars", 0, 179, empty)
    cv2.createTrackbar("Hue Max", "TrackBars", 179, 179, empty)
    cv2.createTrackbar("Sat Min", "TrackBars", 111, 255, empty)
    cv2.createTrackbar("Sat Max", "TrackBars", 255, 255, empty)
    cv2.createTrackbar("Val Min", "TrackBars", 73, 255, empty)
    cv2.createTrackbar("Val Max", "TrackBars", 255, 255, empty)
 


    while True:
    
        success, img = cap.read()
    
    
        imgHSV = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
        h_min = cv2.getTrackbarPos("Hue Min", "TrackBars")
        h_max = cv2.getTrackbarPos("Hue Max", "TrackBars")
        s_min = cv2.getTrackbarPos("Sat Min", "TrackBars")
        s_max = cv2.getTrackbarPos("Sat Max", "TrackBars")
        v_min = cv2.getTrackbarPos("Val Min", "TrackBars")
        v_max = cv2.getTrackbarPos("Val Max", "TrackBars")
        print(h_min, h_max, s_min, s_max, v_min, v_max)
        lower = np.array([h_min, s_min, v_min])
        upper = np.array([h_max, s_max, v_max])
        mask = cv2.inRange(imgHSV, lower, upper)
        imgResult = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=mask)

        cv2.imshow("Original", img)
        cv2.imshow("HSV", imgHSV)
        cv2.imshow("Mask", mask)
        cv2.imshow("Result", imgResult)

        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF ==ord('q'):
            break
```

This is the code that I would like to implement onto a google meet/zoom. Is it possible?

Comment: What do you mean by implementing in google meet/zoom?

Comment: Ok so I would like to use some of the features. This code makes my camera only detect certain colors. I would like to be able to use this filter in a google meet/zoom.

Comment: it looks like you already found pyvirtualcam. Do you have OBS or Unity Capture to provide a virtual camera interface? The PyPi page for pyvirtualcam has a short example and advice on how to use it.

Comment: Yes I did figure out that I needed pyvirtualcam. I have also downloaded OBS, but I do not know how to do the rest, and cant seem to find it anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out. I don't know whether or not this is the most efficient way possible, but I figured out that you can install the NDI output plug-in for OBS. In OBS I just captured my cv2 window then the NDI plugin makes my OBS an actual output for google meet/zoom to share.